# ARM9 cross compilation error

Tags: c, openssl, arm, cross-platform

I'm a beginner in programming embedded devices. 
While cross compiling a cryptography algorithm (using openssl), it generates an error as shown below. The program doesn't have a problem, since it runs well in the host system (Ubuntu 14).
Did anyone come across this problem ? I tried some of the already posted related questions on cross compilation but didn't solve my problem. 
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Probably your SDK needs opensslconf.h, but is not provided.

Comment: You need OpenSSL configured (and built, probably) for the target environment. Just because your host compiler find it when building natively, doesn't mean the cross compiler (and linker!) will find the library.

Comment: Edited screenshot; really? Why didn't you simply copied the error and pasted it here?

Comment: Try following: Do `locate opensslconf.h` or `find target_usr/include -name opensslconf.h` and `find target_usr/usr/local -name openssl.h` and include the path of parent directory in include list with `-I`.

Comment: @MohitJain because he doesn't know how to ctrl+c in command terminal

Comment: Please remove the picture and add the text of the message you are receiving. Do so by clicking the *Edit* link on your question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know the problem with putting screen shot. Can someone tell me the problem ? I changed it for readability purpose only. @user3528438 what a nasty personality u have.

Comment: @MohitJain thanks. Your suggestion helps but still it generated another error with: 

$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hashSHA.c -lcrypto

 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @habesha The problem is that using a screenshot to represent text makes that text unsearchable, much harder to read, generally strange-looking, and so on. It's simply not what posters here are expected to do.

Comment: Thanks @unwind I understand now, will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**For headers issue:**

Locate the headers and include it using `-I` switch while compilation.

**For linking ussue:**

```
$ locate libcrypto.so
```

You will get the directory libcrypto resides. Let's say the directory is: `target_usr/lib/libcrypto.so`

Now use the following command to ensure correct linking:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hashSHA.c -Ltarget_usr/lib -lcrypto
```

Also make sure to add appropriate include flag and prefer to use some warning and optimization flags (`-W -Wall -O2` for example)

Comment: Are you seriously recommending a cross-compiler for ARM to link in a binary from a `i386-linux-gnu` path? You don't see a problem there?

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but i can only see /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so . Since cross compiling is my first time. I'm not sure if I already have the right opeenssl for my target. Could you pls point me other resource or tell me how to set up openssl for ARM9 ?

Comment: Compile or install libcrypto.so for your platform. Make sure it is for correct platform with `file` command.